# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a string variable which stores date from date picker but when I use its value in other function I am getting error like Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. Note: variable is globally defined.

code :

```
    - (void) changedDate: (UIDatePicker *) picker 
    {
     if (appDelegate.dateint == 8)
     {
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
     datestr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dptpicker date]]; 
    NSLog(@"date:%@",datestr); 
    } 
    else if(appDelegate.dateint == 9) 
    { NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"]; 
    datestr1=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dptpicker date]] ;
     NSLog(@"date1:%@",datestr1);
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to retain that string.  This is the most likely reason.

Edit:
The only reason why it is crashing is the bad pointer. The bad pointer = over-releasing the object. Just run your app with zombies enabled and you'll see the place where you're doing that. Check this http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Comment: @ Max  I have already retain that string. Any other solution?

Comment: Post the code where you're getting crash. And the stack trace.

Comment: And even if you're retaining the string it doesn't mean that you're not over-releasing it. Also make sure that you are not calling some extra autorelease messages.

Comment: - (void) changedDate: (UIDatePicker *) picker 
{
 if (appDelegate.dateint == 8) {
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
 
 datestr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dptpicker date]];
  NSLog(@"date:%@",datestr);
  
 }
 else if(appDelegate.dateint == 9) {
   
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
  
  datestr1=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dptpicker date]] ;
  NSLog(@"date1:%@",datestr1);
  
 }

 
}

Comment: its crashing on applying NSlog on datestr and datestr1 variable in different function

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing on NSLog and not here datestr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dptpicker date]]; ?

Comment: @ Max Yes its crashing on NSLog(@"%@",datestr) in different function

Comment: As Max is suggesting, perhaps the dptpicker pointer is bad and you are crashing in [dptpicker date]. Also, is dptpicker a global variable? It is not declared in your example code, but the parameter changedDate:picker: is.

Comment: What do you mean in different function? The only reason why it is crashing is the bad pointer. The bad pointer = over-releasing the object. Just run your app with zombies enabled and you'll see the place where you're doing that. Check this http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Answer (score 3):

Whenever there is a crash, post the backtrace.

Before you do, use "build and analyze" and fix any problems it identifies.

After doing that, if it still crashes, then do a pass with Zombie detection on and see if you are over-releasing something (which is likely, that code has an obvious over-release problem as is).

If it is *still* crashing, then we'll need to see more code....