# xcode phonegap error and how to fix?

Tags: xcode, cordova

i am using xcode 4.2 and phone gap and keep running into

> Thread1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I am new to iphone development and objectiveC programming.

I was just trying to make a simple form and it crashes every time I enter text.

Comment: Any additional info on this bug? What application do you launch(code sample)? Any additional log messages? How to reproduce it?

Comment: Sorry for the brief explanation, this is my first time using it. I'm just using the code provided by phone gap when you set up your first project. all I did was enter a simple form with one input field and when i run it , it crashes after i try to input text. This is the only error i get

Comment: Hmm, it's a little bit hard to get what's wrong when so few info available. I just've downloaded latest PhoneGap lib(v.1.4.1), created a new XCode project (file->new project->PhoneGap based application) and launched it successfully without any changes: http://i.4pcbr.com/i/1d/1rVW9m.png ( all my logs in right bottom corner). Could you post here your log output?

Comment: @4pcbr, i too can get it working without changing anything. The problem came from when i added an input box and tried to test it, the whole thing crashed. I did find a work around, i am using JQuery mobile and i managed to get it working without any errors, so i would recommend this approach

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163494/program-received-signal-exc-bad-access

Comment: problem solved, all i had to do was update phonegap's simulator and all is well. Error has gone and i can now begin to play around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, all I had to do was update the sim and everything worked aas it should! Thanks for the help